# How to show that if a rational sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then $(1/x_n)$ is also Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am struggling to prove the following:

> If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb Q$ with $x_n\nrightarrow0$, then the sequence $(1/x_n)$ is also Cauchy.

My attempt at proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $x_n\nrightarrow0$, it grants us some $\epsilon'>0$ so that for all $N\in\mathbb N$, $|x_n|\ge\epsilon'$ for some $n>N$. [......] The sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded below by some $M>0$. Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, there is $N'\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $|x_m-x_n|<M^2\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N'$. Choose $N=N'$. Then for $m,n>N$,

$$\displaystyle\left|\frac{1}{x_m}-\frac{1}{x_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x_n-x_m}{x_mx_n}\right|=\frac{|x_n-x_m|}{|x_m||x_n|}<\frac{M^2 \epsilon}{M^2}=\epsilon.$$

I am struggling to fill in the blank [......] part. I want to show that $(x_n)$ is bounded below by some positive real number $M>0$, i.e. $x_n\ge M$ for all $n$. I am thinking about constructing a positive subsequence of $(x_n)$ but I am not sure where to start. If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$, then I can easily use the completeness of $\mathbb R$ to show that $(x_n)$ is bounded below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't claim that on the sequence $x_n$ itself, but you can prove that for the sequence of absolute values $|x_n|$. (which is what you actually need) Also, that is not necessary true for all $n$, but only when $n$ is sufficiently large.

**Hint:** As you pointed out, there is some $\epsilon'>0$ such that $|x_n|\geq\epsilon'$ for infinitely many values of $n$. But note that $|x_n|$ is a Cauchy sequence (why?), and so if $m$ and $n$ are sufficiently large then $|x_m|$ and $|x_n|$ are very close to each other. Try to conclude that if $n$ is large enough, we will always have $|x_n|>\frac{\epsilon'}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So after choosing $N$ s.t. $|x_m-x_n|<\frac12\epsilon’$ for all $m,n>N$, I get some $m^\ast$ s.t. $|x_{m^\ast}|\ge\epsilon’$. Then for all $n>N$, $\epsilon’-|x_n|\le|x_{m^\ast}|-|x_n|\le |x_{m^\ast}-x_n|<\frac12\epsilon’$. With this I get $|x_n|>\frac{\epsilon’}{2}$?

Comment: @JohnDavies Yes, exactly. Of course, the index $m^*$ is taken to be larger than $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence then it is convergent. Let $x=\lim x_n.$  Then $x\neq 0$ by assumption. Thus $\lim x_n^{-1}={x^{-1}}.$ In particular $x_n^{-1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: True, but my guess is that OP tried to solve it without using the real numbers. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense to make the assumption that it is a rational sequence.